# PHP PDO statement with varying parameter counts

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo, prepared-statement

I've recently started using php PDO to prevent from SQL injection, I'm having a problem with the statement though as it will change depending on the parameters I'm passing through the URL to change the pages results. The part that I'm struggling on is how can I add the `$_GET['cat_id']` for when the URL has a cat_id to my execute array. Here's a working version but obviously is prone to SQL injection, thanks in advance for any help!

**PHP**

```
$and = '';
if (isset($_GET['cat_id'])) {
    $and = "AND art_cat_id = ".$_GET['cat_id'];
}   

$statement_article = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM app_articles WHERE art_sta_id = :art_sta_id $and ORDER BY art_date DESC");

$statement_article->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

$statement_article->execute(array(':art_sta_id' => "1"));
```

Here's what I tried but it fails if there is no `cat_id` in the url

**PHP**

```
$and = '';
if (isset($_GET['cat_id'])) {
    $and = "AND art_cat_id = :cat_id";
}


$statement_article = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM app_articles WHERE art_sta_id = :art_sta_id $and ORDER BY art_date DESC");

$statement_article->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

$statement_article->execute(array(':art_sta_id' => "1",':cat_id' => $_GET['cat_id']));
```

Comment: "Here's what I tried but it fails if there is no cat_id in the url" --- so don't pass it to the `execute()` if there is no such in the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the parameter array when there's a cat_id:

```
$and = '';
$params = array(':art_sta_id' => "1");

if (isset($_GET['cat_id'])) 
{
  $and = "AND art_cat_id = :cat_id"
  $params[':cat_id'] = $_GET['cat_id'];
}   

$statement_article = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM app_articles WHERE art_sta_id = :art_sta_id $and ORDER BY art_date DESC");

$statement_article->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

$statement_article->execute($params);
```

Comment: Awesome thank you very much, I should have been able to figure that out I've just been coding for way to many hours now hahaha thanks so much!